# AngularJS ng-repeat does not update after Ajax call

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, dom, data-binding

I have an AngularJS applcation.
On the right side of the application I keep the chat with my clients.

The html is the following:

```
<div class="recent" ng-show="show_chat_list">
    <h2></h2>
    <div ng-repeat="customer in recent_customer_list track by $index" ng-click="start_chat(recent_client_id[$index])" class='user'>
        <a href="#" ng-class="{'red-background': notify[$index]}">
            <img ng-src="">
            <div class="user-data">
                <span class='name'> {{ notify }} </span>
                <span class='name'>{{ customer.name }}</span>
            </div>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I updated the list through a factory that do polling every second for new unformation:

```
factory('Poller', ["$http", "store", "URL", function($http, store, URL){

    var data = {
        "hairdresser_id": store.get("userId")
    }

    var poller = function(){
        return $http.post(URL.url + 'check_for_notifications', data).then(function(res){
            return(res.data);
        });
    }

    return {
        poll: poller
    };
}]);
```

In the controller:

```
pollData();

function pollData(){
    Poller.poll().then(function(res){
        $scope.recent_customers_list = res.customers;
        console.log($scope.recent_customers_list[0].name);
        $scope.recent_client_id = res.clients_id;
        $scope.notify = res.notify;
        $timeout(pollData, 1000);
    });
}
```

The console.log function print always the correct name (even if I change it) but in the html does not reflect dynamic change of the list of clients (if I change names or add a client for example).

If I insert

```
$scope.$apply();
```

or

```
$scope.$digest;
```

right before the $timeout line I get the error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress
```

insted if I insert apply right after the line functino pollData() and before the line Poller.poll() I get this error:

```
Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $apply already in progress
```

But my list is not updated at all. I need to refresh to see the changes.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your controller, you are using

```
$scope.recent_customers_list
```

but in your html, you are using

```
recent_customer_list
```

I believe this is a simple typo.

Comment: I love you. I was desperate :)